# Behaviour of 1>&0 in bash

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

So I am trying to learn more about file descriptors and their redirections. At the moment I am exploring an edge case of doing `1>&0` and I cannot quite understand what is happening there.

```
$ echo hello 1>&0
hello
```

So in this case, `hello` is printed even though I redirected stdout to stdin. I expected nothing to be printed.

Can you explain to me why `hello` is printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both descriptors `0` and `1` were connected to your terminal in read + write mode, so this redirection changes nothing. On Linux, you can find all your current descriptors under `/proc/self/fd`, for example in my case:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
lrwx------ 1 jimmij jimmij 64 Jan  3 17:42 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 jimmij jimmij 64 Jan  3 17:42 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 jimmij jimmij 64 Jan  3 17:42 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 jimmij jimmij 64 Jan  3 17:42 3 -> /proc/5263/fd
```

As you can see `0`, `1` and `2` are all linked to pseudoterminal `/dev/pts/2`.

Comment: So /dev/pts/2 is used to provide input to a command but it is also used to capture its output. It seems strange to me that the same resource can do both things. How is it prevented that a command doesn't get as input its own output?

Comment: You are connected to a pseudo terminal. This is a "virtualization" of a real hardware [terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) consisting of Inputdevice(Keyboard) and Outputdevice(Monitor/Printer). It's like a phone which allows you to speak and listen a the same time.

Comment: @clime Well, the same way you can treat your hard disk `/dev/sda` as input and output of the program. Remember that we are talking about *device*, not plain file. Nowadays we use pseudo-terminals like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`, not real devices, but long time ago terminal was large piece of equipment.

Comment: @clime - with a little indirection, you can get the i/o pretty mixed up. Terminal i/o is [pretty strictly defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html) to not work out the way you say - such that a command winds up reading its own output, but doing something like `tee </dev/tty /dev/tty` can get interesting. If you indirect in the same way to a device file that *won't* flush by line as a canonical-mode terminal does... `echo repeat | tee /dev/fd/0` like the pipe there, it gets really interesting.